# How do I change my guild slash commands to global commands?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to switch my guild commands to global commands. They were usable in one specific guild, but now I would like all the servers my bot is in to use these commands. I have provided my code below:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('All set and ready to go!')
    let guild = process.env.GUILD

    const start = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('start')
        .setDescription('Start a new game lobby')
        .addStringOption(options => options
            .setName('game')
            .setDescription('The kind of game you want to start')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
                {
                    name: 'Never Have I Ever',
                    value: 'nhie'
                },
                {
                    name: "Would You Rather",
                    value: 'wyr'
                }
            )
        )

    client.application.commands.create(start, guild)

    const end = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('end')
        .setDescription('Ends the current game')

    client.application.commands.create(end, guild)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To register commands globally, you need to convert your **SlashCommandBuilder** into **JSON** format and then pass it into the `create` function.

```js
client.application.commands.create(start.toJSON());
```

Replace '`start`' with the constant name declared for each **SlashCommandBuilder**. Please note that there might be a delay in deploying commands globally as it can take some time.